# Python: From dictionary to csv with replicating keys by the length of values

Tags: python, pandas, dictionary

I have the following dictionary:

```
import pandas as pd
dict_item = {'item1': ['bag', 'phone', 'laptop'],'item2': ['sofa', 'TV', 'bed', 'door', 'window'] }
```

and I would like to transform it to csv, so far I tried:

```
df = df.append(pd.DataFrame(data={'item_number':dict_item.keys(),'items':dict_item.values()}))
df
```

but it gives me following:

[image]

But I would like to get following:

[image]

So, in other words I would like to replicate the first column which is the keys of dictionary by length of corresponding values

P.S. I created the desired output manually.

Thanks, I would appreciate any help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just using `DataFrame` constructor then `stack`

```
s=pd.DataFrame(list(dict_item.values()),index=dict_item.keys()).stack().reset_index(level=0)
s.columns=['item_number','items']
s
Out[609]: 
  item_number   items
0       item1     bag
1       item1   phone
2       item1  laptop
0       item2    sofa
1       item2      TV
2       item2     bed
3       item2    door
4       item2  window
```

Comment: Thanks, it works but the only problem that i faced is the index. As u see from output, the index starts to repeat when it turns to next item. when i use `sort_index()` in this case i have index like : 0, 0, 1, 1, 2, 2 and etc. do you have any suggestion about that issue?

Comment: @Sascha you can add `s.reset_index(drop=True,inplace=True)`

Answer (score 1):

Use [`json_normalize`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.io.json.json_normalize.html) + [`melt`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.melt.html)

```
df = pd.io.json.json_normalize(dict_item)

expand(df.melt(), 'value')
```

where

```
def expand(df, col):
    d = {c: df[c].values.repeat(df[col].str.len(), axis=0) for c in df.columns}
    d[col] = [i for sub in df[col] for i in sub]
    return pd.DataFrame(d)
```

Outputs

```
    variable    value
0   item1       bag
1   item1       phone
2   item1       laptop
3   item2       sofa
4   item2       TV
5   item2       bed
6   item2       door
7   item2       window
```

---

Another option, with `pd.DataFrame` constructor + `melt`

```
pd.DataFrame(dict_item.values(), index=dict_item.keys()).T.melt().dropna()
```